# Read Google spreadsheet with Unity3D

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, spreadsheet

I need to read google spreadsheets in unity, for example read cell B3 or A4.
What code, method or plugin, can I use?
Thanks <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a DLL for unity that can read spreadsheets is here:
[GoSheets](http://www.files.com/shared/56f0683d8e477/GoSheets.zip).

To use import the DLL in your assets folder and write a script like this:

```
string url = "your google sheet tsv link";

void Start()
{
    GoogleSheets gs = this.gameObject.AddComponent<GoogleSheets>();
    gs.GetCell(url, 2, 3, OnRead);
}

void OnRead(string link, int r, int c, string data)
{
    if(data != "")
        Debug.Log(data);
}
```

Enjoy it ;)

Comment: This is perfect! work fine. thanks :)

Comment: @JhonnyBeGod does this still work? I add the DLL to my assets folder, its referenced in my project but there is no GoogleSheets object.

Comment: @Nolemonpledge if you stil interest, looks like there are changes in dll or misspell in answer, there must be GoSheet type, not GoogleSheets. But there one more problem after that...I got log message unsupported encoding and dunno how to fix it =\